# Index of button has different value onClick than what it displays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button, that is part of an array in jsx.

The button displays the index, 1, 2, 3, etc.
When I press the button however and console log it I get the same value each time, the length of the for loop.
I cannot wrap my head around it. I was thinking of maybe having the wrong keys and coupling two components, but that's not the problem.

```
 const getRows = () => {
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(dropped2 && dropped2.length, dropped1 && dropped1.length); i++) {
      console.log(i);
      rows.push(
        <div key={i}>
          <Browser>
            <DropItArranged left dropped={dropped2 && dropped2.length > i && dropped2[i]} index={i} selected={displayIndex === i} />
            <DropItArranged dropped={dropped1 && dropped1.length > i && dropped1[i]} index={i} selected={displayIndex === i} />
            <button key={"selectButton" + i} className={displayIndex === i ? "button is-link" : "button"} onClick={e => { console.log(i); dispatch(allActions.changeDisplayedContent(i)) }} > {i}</button>
          </Browser>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return rows;
  }
```

Output is always the length of the for loop.

Here is a clean version:

```
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(dropped2 && dropped2.length, dropped1 && dropped1.length); i++) {
      rows.push(
        <div key={i}>
             <button key={"selectButton" + i} onClick={e => { console.log(i); } > {i} </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return rows;
```

This is the return function:

```
return (
    <LeftPanel>
      <div>
        <h5 className="title is-5">Browse</h5>
      </div>
      <Column>
        {getRows()}
      </Column>
    </LeftPanel>
  )
```

Comment: button does not have property key - try to use id

Comment: thanks, I tried this, but the problem remains. I'm really puzzled.

Comment: Use `.map()`, with `for` loop you end up with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change `var i = 0` into `let i = 0`.
Your issue relate to the Scope variable in Javascript.
`The main difference between let and var is that scope of a variable defined with let is limited to the block in which it is declared while variable declared with var has the global scope.`

For this case, when you use `let` instead, there is a new variable `i` created for each invocation of the loop that is scoped just to the block of the loop. So, you can have new variable for each `console.log`. Following this one for more detail: [JavaScript: Understanding let scope inside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170277/javascript-understanding-let-scope-inside-for-loop)

Comment: The issue about let and var only happens when they are handled in an async way. Here I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: I dont think so. `let` and `var` has different scope so the issue can happen in each code line, not just async way.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I always write it with let, so I have not encountered this error before (I copied a part of the code). I appreciate your and other's input!