# How does the let scope work in a for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope

I have a question about how the `let` scope work in a `for` loop, regarding the following examples.

```js
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
    setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log(i);
  },1000)
}
// will print out 0,1,2,3,4
```

```js
for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
    setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log(j);
  },0)
}
// will print out 5,5,5,5,5
```

I know the difference between `var` and `let`. The `var` has a function scope and the `let` has a block scope.
For the `let` one, though the `i` is inside the `for` loop, the `console.log(i)` always take in the same variable `i`. The variable `i` is updated in each iteration. So when the `setTimeout` callback functions are executed, they have the same `i`, and they should print the same number, which is `5` here.
The `var` and `let` have different scope, but both are updated in each iteration, and both variables are logged at the end. Shouldn't they have the same result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: There is an additional layer of scoping here with the fat arrow `() => {}` construct. This creates what is called a "closure". I suggest you google "javascript closure" or something similar to learn more about how it works.

Comment: "*the `console.log(i)` always take in the same variable `i`*" - no, it doesn't. Every closure closes over a different variable `i`, as - as you say - it is created inside the loop.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think he understands closures. What wasn't clear is that there's a separate scope for each iteration of the loop, not a single scope for the entire loop.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I understand closures. Thanks for your keyword _separate scope_. I found another question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170277/javascript-understanding-let-scope-inside-for-loop.   Now I know the `i` are different variables in each iteration.